# BMD of the beam joined at intersection

Tags: moments, bending

4 beams are supported by the column at one side, another side is jointed together at the intersection. I have assigned UDL of 20 kN/m on all the beams. 2 beams are longer (3m), 2 beams are shorter (2m) . Surprisingly, the BMD of the longer beams is hogging at the middle part , while the BMD of the shorter beams is sagging at th middle. Does it make sense.

Can someone explain this situation ? Why the BMD of the longer beam is hogging at the middle ? There's no column at the middle , how can there's hogging moment at the middle for the longer beam ?

I think the BMD of the shorter beam make sense and the BMD of the longer beam shall be teh same also (pure sagging in the middle and no sagging at all. ) Correct me if I am wrong ..[image: hi]

Comment: If the moment of inertia of the beams is identical, then the shorter beam is stiffer and acting as a support to the long beam, which is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are an engineering student, you understand that beam deflects under load, and the longer the more flexible than the shorter beam, thus deflect more. The answer to this problem can be worked out from the concept of "beam on elastic (deflectable/settled) support"

For your case, with the identical uniform load on both beams, it is obvious that the deflection of the longer beam (let's call d1) exceeds the shorter beam deflection (d2), if the parameters A, I, E are identical to both beam and the end support type is the same (fixed or simply supported), because d = nL^4/mEI (n & m are deflection constants). But in reality, the two beams must deflect to the same magnitude due to geometry compability, so we realize there must be something to make d1' = d2' = d. This something is "rigidity", which is the inverse of "flexibility".

Rigidity = 1/Flexibility

Flexibility is a function of deflection, d, thus rigidity = 1/d. In structural engineering, the rigidity can be defined as the deflection caused by a unit load 1, so it has a unit of force/length, which is identical to the spring constant, k = P/d.

Practically, the longer beam is sitting on the more rigid shorter beam, which is similar to been supported at the intersecting point by a spring. The spring represents the rigidity of the shorter beam, and as defined above, k = 1/d2. it is graphically shown in the diagram below. The spring will bring the beams into an equilibrium position (d1'= d2'= d) and will exert an upward force in the longer beam, which results in the negative (hogging) moment in the longer beam. Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the selection of constraints you have selected it is as if the longer beam (C and D) is resting (or is being supported by) the shorter beam (A and B).

[image]

What happens is that while the load is distributed among the individual beams, the bending moments and the lengths are different.

Therefore *independently* the longer beam (assuming they have the same geometric constraints) are prone to more deflection. However due to the constrain imposed by the central joint, the shorter beams resist to the deflection (offer support).
Therefore the shorter beams will deflect more, while the longer beams will deflect less.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how's the beam are being supported. I just drew 4 broken linesthat are joined at the interscetion only and I want to see how's the beam behave only. I am not sure whether the BMD of the system is correct or not

Comment: Ok, that clear it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your diagram. if this is the moment diagram the short beam moment  diagram should be a superposition of a triangle due the concentrated load from the long beam and the parabola due to the uniform load on the beam. And it is. unless your long beam is much stiffer than the shot beam which is highly unusual.

The long beam moment diagram is correct and is similar to the moment diagram of a two span continuous beam supported on a flexible supprt at center.

The flexiblity of the support is rqual to that of a simply supported beam loaded at center.

Comment: In real life, is the bmd correct? Or I shall release the bending moment at the long span so that it sag at the junction?

Comment: in real life it works exactly as what you show. i designed a house in 1992 in Encino, california with the cathedral ceiling ridge beam resting on a perpendicular beam like your diagram. but in our case we took the short beam much stronger to increase the negative moment on the saddle and decrease the positive moment on the middle of each span to minimize the size of the long beam.